# What is this pattern on the windshield of aircraft?

Tags: feature-identification, windscreen

The image is extracted from this Airbus A350 [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gzxgA3zogw&t=219) (at 3m40s, when taking off)[image]

I circled in purple the strange pattern formed by few black straight lines. I'm quite puzzled as I have no idea of what it is or what purpose it can serve.

**EDIT**: I would like to sum up the ideas in comments as there is interesting guess and discussions in the comments. It is a strange *device* which can be:

- a kind of gauge useful as the windscreen seems to be a completely new one and the aircraft presented is one of the test aircraft
- part of some windscreen heating device

Comment: looks like electric windscreen heat to me, but I'll defer to someone with specific systems knowledge of this airplane.

Comment: @casey I would concur if it was not placed there. it cover only a small part of the windscreen.

Comment: @ManuH It doesn't need to cover more area.  I don't know the a350 but it is almost identical to other screen heaters I've seen.  Those things get really hot, they will burn you hand, and the windscreen only needs to be a little above freezing.

Comment: @Simon Ah, so you don't need to be an SR-71 pilot to be able to warm your lunch on the windshield! (As long as you choose the right part of it.)

Comment: Darn, I was really hoping it was the cockpit glass detonation cord for the A350 ejection seat. :-)

Comment: They look like strain gauges to me. Probably to ensure the windows are within the expected force limits.

Comment: @tl8 you may be right. The video shows a test airplane, and I can't find those lines in other videos.

Comment: @casey I agree with you.  They are not heating elements as some others have suggested, but rather an electrical bus which provides electricity to a conductive windshield which heats the entire thing.  I'm not familiar with the specific aircraft, but there are three sets, which probably are for something like high, low, and emergency settings for the windshield heat.

Comment: I agree with @tl8. The lower (and middle) structure also shows white lines, which look like transparent tape to fix that... device to the screen. As said, it's a test plane, and to my knowledge, the wind shields are new, too.

Comment: May be it is shallow

Comment: [This wiki commons cockpit view](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Airbus_A-350_XWB_F-WWYB_cockpit_view.jpg) shows  the same wires, albeit only 1 set. not 3.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Short answer

These are the three redundant temperature sensors for the windscreen anti icing and defogging system. The design is similar to what is found on the A330 and A340, and most large aircraft. The sensors are used to control the electric current in the heating film(s) sandwiched in the windscreen ply. Usually three temperatures are monitored:

- Outer windscreen layer must be above freezing point, e.g. 1.8°C.
- Film mustn't overheat, depends on film used.
- Inner layer must be below some threshold, e.g. 50°C.

[This video](https://www.facebook.com/mzostudio/videos/2763004477259722/) shows how windscreen heating works on an ATR42. Extract related to the sensors:

[image: ATR42 windscreen temperature sensors and film bus bars]
<sup>ATR42 windscreen temperature sensors and film bus bars</sup>

The heating film(s) is/are used both to prevent icing and failure of the outer panel (air temperature can be as low as -60°C) and fogging on the inner panel. This can be obtain using a single film, but sometimes there are two distinct films:

[image: Structure of the windscreen on a Boeing 787]
<sup>Structure of the windscreen on a Boeing 787. [Source](https://thepointsguy.com/news/what-are-airplane-windows-made-of/)</sup>

---

#### On the A350

From [A-350 Technical Training Manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/269894568/30-Ice-and-Rain-Protection-pdf#scribd):

[image]

> **Windows Anti Icing/Defogging Function, Description and Interfaces**
>
> The windows anti icing/defogging system is divided into two
> sub-systems (F/O and CAPT). Each sub-system is comprised of one
> windshield, one FWD lateral window, one AFT lateral window and a
> Window Heat Computer (WHC). [...]
>
> The anti icing and defogging function of the cockpit
> windshields is ensured by the heating of one resistive/heating ﬁlm. Each
> windshield's resistive heating ﬁlm is powered by 230 VAC, provided by
> the WHC.
>
> **There are three temperature sensors near the heating ﬁlm** that
> continually send information to the WHC for the heating regulation and
> the overheat protection functions. [...]
>
> The WHC regulates the temperature of the cockpit windows (35 degrees C to
> 42 degrees C) based on the temperature value it receives from one of the three temperature sensors. The other two temperature sensors are
> in standby mode. [...]
>
> If the temperature of the cockpit windows reaches a specific
> temperature level (+60 degrees C), the WHC will stop supplying the
> specific window. [...] For each window, the WHC uses temperature
> values from the three temperature sensors to detect an overheat.
>
> The WHCs interface and exchange data via CRDCs with the
> AFDX network.The two WHCs are located in the cockpit: WHC1 is located
> next to the fourth occupant console behind the Captain. WHC2 is
> located next to the coat stowage behind the First Ofﬁcer.

For this test aircraft:

- Sensors are larger than usual.
- They may be stuck on the glass instead of being built-in.

This setting might be specific for flight test purposes. Someone may bring additional elements.

---

Another example, on a [Pilatus PC12-NG](http://www.planes.cz/cs/photo/1123348/pilatus-pc-12ng-ok-pca-private-mimo-letiste):

[image: Pilatus PC12-NG temperature sensors and bus bars on the windscreen]
<sup>Pilatus PC12-NG temperature sensors and bus bars on the windscreen</sup>

Comment: The inner layer must also be above ambient temperature inside cockpit to prevent the fogging (or at least above dew point, but that's not known).

Comment: @JanHudec: True, but with a cabin RH of 20% at 20°C, the dew point is below 0°C. So that would be a problem only prior to closing the doors.