# What's the technical name of the side window on Boeing and on Embraer?

Tags: aircraft-design, terminology

On Airbus, the window beside the Captain and the First Officer has the technical name of SIDE WINDOW.
What's the name on other aircraft, or they have the same specification?

Comment: I fail to see which window you are refering to. You may add a picture highlighting it.

Comment: "Side window" sounds like a purely decriptive term, to me, and not a technical term.

Comment: Adding to @DavidRicherby comment, other "names" exist on Airbus documentation: [What is this pattern on the A350 front window?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/what-is-this-pattern-on-the-a350-front-window/20887#20887)

Answer (score 3):

The windows to the side of the pilots on the Embraer airplanes are called "Direct Vision" (DV) windows.   They are named as such because they can be opened and removed both during normal ops on the ground and [emergency ops while airborne](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13075/258) to provide forward vision when the main windscreens are obscured.

Answer (score 3):

For Boeing, the captain's side window is the L2 window, with L1 in front of him, R1 in front of the coplilot, and R2 being the copilot's sliding window. The L3 and R3 window are aft of the sliding windows.