# What is this stripe on the windshield of the Embraer E-Jet?

Tags: feature-identification, windows, embraer-e-jet

I noticed that there is a stripe along the upper edge of both forward windshields in the Embraer E-Jets:

[image: E-Jet]
<sup>(cropped from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Embraer_190-100LR,_China_Southern_Airlines_JP7321016.jpg))</sup>

I tried to find a better picture, but couldn't find anything closer. [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLS35nv-4IQ) clearly shows the stripe several times:

[image: E-Jet]

**What is this stripe used for?** The only thing I can think of is window heating, but these elements usually look quite different, as can be here: [What is this pattern on the A350 front window?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/what-is-this-pattern-on-the-a350-front-window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a heater bus bar. In fact, the Q/A about the sensor loops that you linked has a great example of the same if you scroll to the bottom of the best answer.

Comment: So there should be another of these at the bottom (probably hidden behind the glareshield) and then current flows between them for heating?

Comment: @Bianfable Of course you're right, in fact you can see them from the outside: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HEWumjfD6w4/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Having never been in the cockpit of an Embraer E-Jet, I would have guessed it was a rod to move the sun shade left to right on  to adjust for the angle of the sun.